# How to create instances of a class within a loop?

Tags: python, class

So I got the following problem. Let's say I want to make a game and therefore I have a list of players. To work with this players and give them several attributes I create a `Players` class. Now I want to automatically paste every player in my list as a separate instance in my `Players` class.

```
class Players:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.player_name = name


players_arr = ['Testplayer1', 'Testplayer2', 'Testplayer3']


# Testplayer1 = Players(name = players_arr[0])
# Testplayer2 = Players(name = players_arr[1])
# Testplayer3 = Players(name = players_arr[2])
```

Any idea how I could automate the process commented out? I basicly want to create this class because everyone has a counter (imagine like a death counter) and of course it has to tick separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try comprehension list:

```
Testplayer = [Players(p) for p in players_arr]
Testplayer

Output: [<__main__.Players at 0x14225308438>,
        <__main__.Players at 0x14225308ba8>,
        <__main__.Players at 0x14225308be0>]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Players:
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.player_name = name


players_arr = ['Testplayer1', 'Testplayer2', 'Testplayer3']
players_objs = []
for player in players_arr :
    players_objs.append(Players(name = player))
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I did know, that you can add instances to a list..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `globals()` dictionary which is responsible for your namespace.

```
for n in players_arr:
    globals()[n] = Players(n)
print(Testplayer1, Testplayer2, Testplayer3) #checking if it works
```

However, this is not advised. Using comprehensions is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend that you name your class in the singular: `Player`.  The class defines a single player.

If you need merely a tractable sequence of player objects, then create them with a simple list comprehension:

```
player_name = ['Testplayer1', 'Testplayer2', 'Testplayer3']
player_objs = [Player() for _ in len(player_arr)]
```

However, if you *do* need the players associated with a regular sequence of names, then use a dict, and build the names as you iterate:

```
player_table = {"TestPlayer" + str(i) : Player() for i in range(n)}
```

Where `n` is the quantity of players you want.